# How can I scrape data of ```title``` and ```genres``` in Russian?

Tags: python, web-scraping, imdb, imdbpy

Here is my code, so how can I scrap data of `title` and `genres` in Russian or any other language (now I have it in English)?

```
from imdb import IMDb

def scrape_movie_info(movie_id):
    ia = IMDb('http', useModule='http')
    movie = ia.get_movie(movie_id)#

    print("Название: ", movie["title"])
    print("Рейтинг: ", movie["rating"])
    print("Жанры: ", movie["genres"])
    print("Описание: ", movie["plot outline"])#

movie_id = "20225374"
scrape_movie_info(movie_id)
```

Comment: Re *"scrap"*: Do you mean *"[scrape](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scrape#Verb)"*?

Comment: I don't see anything in the imdbpy source that handles different languages.

Comment: Check if this exists: https://github.com/cinemagoer/cinemagoer/issues/329

Comment: @tevemadar Thank you very much! Please, answer the question with your comment, I will accept it and mark it as useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be multiple fields:

- `movie['title']` usually produces an English title
- `movie['original title']` is the title of the movie in its country of origin
- and there is a `movie['localized title']` which may already give you Russian title, based on your IP and/or system settings.

Then according to a feature request in their issue tracker, https://github.com/cinemagoer/cinemagoer/issues/329, you can specify preferred languages in the initialization,

> ```
> ia = imdb.IMDb('https', languages='it-IT')
> ```

is the example there, and it presumably becomes

```
ia = IMDb('http', useModule='http', languages='ru-RU')
```

when applied to your particular code.